# jquery not running in chrome, works in ff

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I've been building and testing in ff, now checking in chrome. Everything works great except that the jquery doesn't run. 
I seem to recall running into this issue before, but I can't remember how to fix it.

I'm working in a rails app, here's the script I want to run:

**EDITED**

The alert comes up when the page loads, but the ready function never executes. sooo hopefully that narrows down the issue a little.

```
<script>
alert("hi")
$(document).ready(function () {
var theButton = $('#back-to-top');
var theButtonWidthOverTwo = theButton.width()/2;
theButton.css('top', $(window).height()-60);
theButton.css('right', $(window).width()/2-theButtonWidthOverTwo);
theButton.on("click", function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast");
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    theButton.css('top', $(window).height()-60);
    theButton.css('right', $(window).width()/2-theButtonWidthOverTwo);
});
$("#club-posts-table").tablesorter();
});
</script>
```

Tablesorter is from the plugin of the same name (installed as a gem).

And there's a button with a short function:

```
<button id="back-to-top" class="pink" onclick="$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');" style="position: fixed;bottom:0;z-index: 10; width: 240px;opacity: 0.3;">Back To Top</button>
```

So basically none of this stuff runs in chrome. I also tried moving the script to an actual js file so it would be part of the asset pipeline, but it didn't work. 
Tablesorter aside, the code in the ready function and the button shouldn't need any help running.

**EDIT 2** the whole file:

```
<div id="container-new-admin">


  <button class="pink" onclick="window.location='<%= session[:back_button_url]%>';" style="width:200px;position:relative;margin:10px auto">Back</button>

  <% if @posts_array != nil %>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">All Posts By Members of <%= get_club_name_by_id %></h1>

  <table id="club-posts-table" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <td>Poster</td>
    <td>Thumbnail</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Num Comments</td>
    <td>Num Elevates</td>
    <td>Date Posted</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @posts_array.each do |p| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= p.user.username %></td>
          <td><a href="/post/<%= p.id %>" target="_blank"><%= load_image_only_if_exists(p) %></a></td>
          <td><%= p.post_text %></td>
          <td><%= p.comments.length %></td>
          <td><%= p.post_elevations.length %></td>
          <td><%= p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% else %>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Try again, using a club id this time...</h1>

  <% end %>
  <button id="back-to-top" class="pink">Back To Top</button>
</div>

<script>
****see above****
</script
```

Comment: It worked for me when I moved the onclick code into the script. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/59fj6ze6/)

Comment: I think it has to do with when different scripts get evaluated. Generally, you shouldn't put event handlers in the HTML like that. You're manipulating `theButton` in a separate script anyway. Might as well set the click handler there.

Comment: hm, your fiddle works for me, too, but doesn't fix it in my website. The script even (partially) works when I take the styling off the button. I was getting the chrome double scrollbars, where for whatever reason the button was being treated like an iframe, and it _would_ scroll to the top of its messed up frame. But then, there's the issue with tablesorter not functioning either..

Comment: but ill move the click handler with the other event handlers in the script.

Comment: Weird. I don't know, then.

Comment: I've also tried removing the ready function that surrounds the code, which actually gets most of the code working, but doesn't do the move back to the top, or the tablesort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone else who comes across this, it was down to some weird interpretations of heights, I'm not exactly sure why, but chrome seemed to think that the $('body').scrollTop value was always 0.

When I inspected the body and unchecked the two places it's height was being set to 100%, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I think doing this only with css will be easier. Please find the demo in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0gzzu2e5/).

The onclick handler is also working in the demo but I think it's better to add the handler in the script (as proposed in the comments).

```js
//$(function(){$("#club-posts-table").tablesorter();});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var theButton = $('#back-to-top');
    
    /* works but css is even simpler - one line in css with :hover
    var show = function() {
        $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
    };
    var hide = function() {
        $(this).css('opacity','0.3')
    };
    
    // hover(inHandler, outHandler)
    theButton.hover(show, hide);
    */
    
    /* works but hover is easier
    theButton.on("mouseover", function() {
        theButton.css('opacity','1.0')
    });
    
    theButton.on("mouseout", function() {
        theButton.css('opacity','0.3')
    });*/
    
    theButton.click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

```css
button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444;
    min-width: 90px;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#back-to-top {
    z-index: 10; 
    width: 240px;
    max-width: 100%;   /* Make it fit window if under 500px */ 
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
 
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.

Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis
</div>
<div class="footer">
<button id="back-to-top" class="pink">Back To Top</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I like the css for the hover, but the main issue still stands that the actual scroll up doesn't work.

Comment: It sure does for me. I even [added a table](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/bud53nwd/) to @AWolf's fiddle just to make sure tablesorter wasn't causing problems. Can you update the question to include more of the actual HTML?

Comment: i added the whole file contents, it's not that big.

Comment: oh, yeah it works for me in the fiddle, too. this is defintiely an issue with chrome not loading/not running the script, not with any errors in the script itself.